# Why are these two shapefiles different?

Tags: shapefile

Can someone please explain why these two shapefiles are different:

1. [Neighborhoods in Cambridge, MA](https://www.cambridgema.gov/GIS/gisdatadictionary/Boundary/BOUNDARY_CDDNeighborhoods.aspx) ; and
2. [Water bodies in Cambridge, MA](https://www.cambridgema.gov/GIS/gisdatadictionary/Hydro/HYDRO_WaterBodies.aspx).

In particular, I am having trouble working with the water bodies shapefile. The program I am using (Stata) gives the following error message when I try to work with the water shapefile: "point, polyine, or polygon shapefile required." However, the neighborhood shapefile works just fine.

Comment: Hi, the link to the water bodies shapefile is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Neighborhoods are plain old Polygons.
The Water is Polygons with  ZM Values.

[This](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=988&t=272505) is likely your fix. Remove the Z and M values and I suspect Stata will read it.